# Does Heroku support RPC (i.e. gRPC)?

Tags: heroku, grpc

Looks like Google App Engine [didn't support it](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grpc-io/3KYVLrNJiT4) yet as of early 2015. Does Heroku support it? Wondering what does it take, shouldn't it work if we deploy all appropriate dependency and use the right port? (assuming authentication will be taken care of)

Comment: This feature is very much needed.
Did you find anything useful? Workaround to use this: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-firestore

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Heroku only accepts incoming requests on Port 80 and Port 443. That'll probably be the limiting factor.

Comment: I see, so even if grpc specifies port 80 or 443, it's no use since those two ports are reserved for web (80 or 443)? -Apologies for lack of experience on ports, I may just try to spin up a grpc server using port 80 and what may happen...

Comment: so infact, your app actually runs on a port that we set in the PORT environment variable. Our router then proxies requests it receives on port 80 to your app running on the PORT config var.

Comment: I think this is more about Heroku supporting HTTP/2 than the port number or grpc itself.

Answer (score 8):

No, Heroku doesn't support HTTP/2 required for gRPC to work.

> HTTP/2 is not currently supported on Heroku although this may change in future. You can find out about our currently supported HTTP protocols here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#http-versions-supported